# Rust - Can I make this diesel dsl::find() function more generic?

Tags: database, generics, rust, rust-diesel

I have a function that uses diesel to get an object from a DB based off the given ID:

```
fn get_db_site(pool: web::Data<Pool>, site_id: u32) -> Result<Site, diesel::result::Error> {
    let conn = pool.get().unwrap();                                                           
    dsl::site.find(site_id).get_result::<Site>(&conn)                                         
}
```

This function is going to be exactly the same for every table I want to run it on so I'm hoping to put it in it's own utils file so I don't have to type the same thing in every time. The only problem is in order to call that find I need to do
`crate::schema::site::dsl::site.find` and I'm not sure how I can make that call generic to take any type. I know there are type arguments but I don't think that would work here

Answer (score 1):

I normally advise against making diesel things more generic as this leads to really complex trait bounds quite fast. You normally never want to do this in application code. (It's a different thing for libraries that need to be generic). I normally compare the situation with plain SQL. For example if someone complains that `users::table.find(pk)` feels like duplication, ask yourself the following question: Would you feel that `SELECT … FROM users` is duplicated in the corresponding query `SELECT … FROM users WHERE id = $`. (The diesel dsl statement is basically the same).

So to answer your actual question, the generic functions needs to look something like this:
(Not sure if I got all bounds right without testing)

```rust
fn get_db_thing<'a, T, PK, U>(conn: &mut SqliteConnection, pk: PK) -> QueryResult<U>
where
    T: HasTable<Table = T> + FindDsl<PK>,
    U: Queryable<SqlTypeOf<Find<T, PK>>, Sqlite>,
    <T as FindDsl<PK>>::Output: Expression + LoadQuery<'a, SqliteConnection, U>,
{
    T::table().find(pk).get_result(conn)
}
```

As you can see the list of trait bounds is already much longer than just having the load inline in the corresponding functions. In addition all the details added while constructing the query would now be required as generic function argument. At least the type for `T` cannot be inferred by the compiler, so from a code size point of view this solution is not "simpler" than just not making it generic.